# Issue when install DevStack on Ubuntu Server 16.04 in VMware 14 Pro

Tags: 16.04, openstack, vmware-workstation

My teacher at school has informed me about OpenStack and I searched in the Internet how to install it. I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/) and created a lab on VMware 14.

This is my vm config:

- Ubuntu Server 16.04
- 2 processors (enable VT-x)
- 4 GB RAM
- 1 Network Adapter: NAT (192.168.1.x)

As I follow step by step I have been stuck in some warnings:

[image: warning]

Which ends up like this:

[image: exitonerror]

I searched for other sollution. I uninstalled python then installed it but this didn't fix it. I don't know why?
Already update, solfware were installed before forward to install devstack: `vim`, `git`.

P/S: The same happens in Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I don't know how to extract the text about.

Comment: To copy terminal content you can either 1) select, copy & paste it or (if in a terminal emulator which is not the case here; you have virtual consoles of a virtual machine) 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.